# Why C program 2D array second line replace first line

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

i pass buf to array first is schArray[i][0] = buf;

for example i need  `buf` into `schArray`

```
ABCDEFG to [0][0] 

1234567 to [1][0]
```

but i cannot doing this result

my result second line replace first line

```
Time 1:  [0][0]  = ABCDEFG
         [1][0]  = null

Time 2 :[0][0]  = 1234567
        [1][0]  = 1234567
```

replace [0][0]

```
char ***schArray;

int q,k;

schArray = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char*)*1000);
for(q = 0; q < 1000; q++){

    schArray[q] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

    for(k = 0; k < 1000; k++){
        schArray[q][k] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    }
}

while(strncmp(buf, KEYWORD_endP,KEYWORD_PS_SZ)!=0){
  schArray[commandnum][0] = buf;

  printf("%s\n",schArray[0][0]);
  printf("%s\n",schArray[1][0]);
  printf("%s\n",schArray[2][0]);

  val=printCommand(buf);

  printf("child: %d\n",val);

  // printf("child:%d",val);

  memset(buf, 0, 80);

  write(cTop[i][1],&buf,80*sizeof(char));
  read(pToc[i][0],&buf,80*sizeof(char));
  commandnum++;
}
```

expected output

```
ABCDEFG 

1234567
```

actual output

```
1234567

1234567
```

Comment: `schArray[q] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*100)` should be `schArray[q] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*100)` (correct type; no casting); other than that, your question is unfortunately not clear. Can you provide actual and expected output of your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is this line:

```
schArray[commandnum][0] = buf;
```

This doesn't make a copy of `buf`, it sets the array element to point to the location of `buf`.  So each time you're pointing to the same buffer.

You need to use `strcpy()` to copy the buffer into the array element:

```
strcpy(schArray[commandnum][0], buf);
```

Another issue is with your loop that calls `malloc()`, the `sizeof` parameters are not correct.

```
schArray = malloc(sizeof(char**)*1000);
for(q = 0; q < 1000; q++){
    schArray[q] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*100);
    for(k = 0; k < 1000; k++){
        schArray[q][k] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    }
}
```

You also don't need to cast the result of `malloc()`. It returns `void*`, and this will be automatically converted as needed (in C, but not C++). Including the explicit cast can mask other errors, such as forgetting an `#included` that declares `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't allocate massive arrays of pointers to pointers to characters.  Beginning C programmers are often at first comfortable with using arrays.  Then they want to move into something more complex and start using 2d arrays.  Then they realize that they have to move their stuff to the heap and then they can't seem to let go of the C array scheme and just move on to something more useful.

Specifically, you don't need to access your elements using C array syntax, for example `myarray[3][4]` to access the element at x=3, y=4.  It's time to just start doing the math yourself and save yourself (and others) a massive headache.

```
#define MY_ARRAY_HEIGHT 1000
#define MY_ARRAY_WIDTH 1000

static inline char getElement(char *myArray, unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    return myArray[x + y * MY_ARRAY_WIDTH];
}

int main(void) {
    char *myArray = malloc (MY_ARRAY_HEIGHT * MY_ARRAY_WIDTH);

    // initialize it, etc.
    printf("element at 3,4 = %d\n", getElement(myArray, 3, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, btw, please note that in the `getElement` function, the `y * MY_ARRAY_WIDTH` is not a typo as it may at first seem (multiplying the y value, by the width), that's just how we're laying out our data in memory.  Also, by declaring `getElement` as `static inline`, we eliminate the function call overhead and provide the compiler additional opportunities for optimization.  The generated code (when optimizations are enabled) is likely to be identical to the `myarray[3][4]` C array access if it was declared as `char myarray[MY_ARRAY_WIDTH][MY_ARRAY_HEIGHT];`